# NSBundle mainBundle infoDictionary returns NULL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbundle

No idea why `[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]` returns `nil`...

I have an Info.plist file in the project.. and build settings point to it...

Why is this happening?

Comment: That sounds strange, because (according to the documentation), `infoDictionary` returns a valid dictionary even if there is no Info.plist at all.

Answer (score 0):

`-infoDictionary` should never return a `nil` dictionary. It may be a problem with the Info.plist file itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem cleared. I'm not sure, but I think the solution was to set my Project build settings "Info plist" property to its true path, which was empty before...

Strange problem...